# How to ask about the remaining distance to my friend's house?

Tags: phrase-request

My friend and I have been walking for about 2 kilometers, and now I want to ask her about the remaining distance to the house. What is the usual way to go about this? I have these in mind:

> How far still to go?
>
> How far do we still have to go?
>
> How much distance is left?

Answer (score 1):

*How far do we still have to go?* is OK, but maybe a little wordy. The other ones sound a little awkward to me.

I would suggest the following:

> How much further?
>
> How far to go?
>
> How far is it? / How much further is it?
>
> Can we stop? [My dogs are barking.](https://www.waywordradio.org/dogs-are-barking/)